# Replacing An Amount in a Select Box Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

OK, so I'm comparing 2 values on a webform, one is a text value, and one is in a select element.  When the text value is less than the dropdown I need the dropdown to change to the highest value lower than the one in the text box.

For example, if the user selects 2000 in the dropdown, and then enters 1100 in the text field, I would need the popup to return say 1000.

I wrote the beginnings of something I thought would work, but I can't tell if I should use a return command in conjunction with the dropdown field name, or something like field name (of popup) is < text amount.

Here is what I have so far.  If someone can just point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

```
function compareAmts () {
    if ($("#TCA_Field1").val() < ("#TCA_Field2").val ) {
        ($("#TCA_Field2").val() ==
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I mean a pull down menu. Sick today.

Comment: The stuff inside the if block doesn't make much sense to me. What do you want to occur if one is less than the other? Also, shouldn't `("#TCA_Field2").val` be `$("#TCA_Field2").val()`?

Comment: I want the value in the second field, which is a pull down to decrement to the value closest (but less than) to the one in the first field.

Comment: @JackParker Could you please post the HTML for the dropdown? Does it have values in steps of 1000?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using plain JavaScript to iterate over the options and select one that's appropriate:

```
function adjustMaxDropdownValue($dropdown, $input)
{
    var element = $dropdown.get(0),
    options = element.options,
    i = element.selectedIndex,
    atMost = +$input.val(); // cast to number

    while (i >= 0 && options[i].value >= atMost) {
        --i;
    }

    element.selectedIndex = i;
}
```

This assumes that your dropdown values are ordered from low to high.

To call:

```
adjustMaxDropdownValue($("#TCA_Field1"), $("#TCA_Field2"));
```

Comment: I think it might be more efficient to pull all option values to an array, use sort, then iterate over that to find the highest one less than `atMost`. Would save cycles compared to decrementing 1 unit at a time, esp if you have large steps like 1000.

Comment: @Asad All the options *are* in an array, the `options` array :)

Comment: I'm trying to play around with it in an attempt to get it to work for me, but it's saying there's a syntax error on the var options line. I can't see it though. Any idea what I would have to do to set it up?

Comment: Do I need to replace (0) with the amount of selections in the drop down in this case 8?

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, however, I have a few questions.  The initial function.  Do I leave those as dropdown and input, or do I rewrite those TCA_Field 1 and 2?  Also, do I switch 0 for 8 in the paretheses? As it stands right now if I put the call into the area that contains the form code it gets a session error upon login, and if I put it with the JS that controls the other form functions I get a syntax error.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to call it? I've noticed most of the JS in this form and others on the website I'm working on have the functionality built into the various functions, and they are not called separately.

Comment: @JackParker I've already mentioned in my answer how the function should be called.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Functions


function compareAmts($FIELDSwitchText, $FIELDSwitchPull)
{
var SwitchAdv = 0;
temp = $("#FIELD_SwitchPull").val();
var SwitchComm = parseInt(temp.replace(/\,/g,''));

if($("#FIELD_SwitchText").val()!=""){
    SwitchAdv = parseInt($("#FIELD_SwitchText").val());
}


var element = $FIELDSwitchText.get(0),
options = element.options,
i = element.selectedIndex,
atMost = +$FIELDSwitchPull.val(); // cast to number

while (i >= 0 && options[i].value >= atMost) {
    --i;
}

element.selectedIndex = i;
```

}

Comment: I'm trying this now, but while I'm not getting an error when I debug the code I get stuck in a Jquery method after running through the Var element section.  Any idea why that could be happening?